# Hibernate Envers 6.4.1: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection

Tags: hibernate-envers, spring-data-envers

I migrate to Hibernate 6.4.1 (via spring boot 3.2.1) and my app logs an error that wasnt' there before:

```
2024-01-03T15:49:10.361+01:00 ERROR 81857 --- [           main] 
o.h.metamodel.internal.MetadataContext   : 
HHH015007: Illegal argument on static metamodel field injection : 
org.hibernate.envers.DefaultRevisionEntity_#class_; expected type :  
org.hibernate.metamodel.model.domain.internal.EntityTypeImpl; encountered type : 
jakarta.persistence.metamodel.MappedSuperclassType
```

I can reproduce this with a minimal example by basically copying the code from spring data envers documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/envers/configuration.html

I can also reproduce this by running the spring-data-envers example:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/main/jpa/envers/pom.xml

I can also reproduce this by running https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/main/hibernate-envers/src/test/java/org/hibernate/orm/test/envers/DefaultAuditTest.java

Created issue https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/boards/31?selectedIssue=HHH-17612

Answer (score 3):

In my case, using the `@Audited` annotation of hibernate envers caused the error. I resolved the error by removing the dependency `implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers"` and adding `implementation "org.hibernate:hibernate-envers-jakarta:5.6.15.Final"`.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, and I flipped out at first, but taking a [closer look at the code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/776c05cad78365982be61ddaa7316dcd38e4f248/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/metamodel/internal/MetadataContext.java#L754), it seems that this used to be a hard fail but now it's only logged as error-- Once I realized that, I sort of kept my fingers crossed and hoped that everything would work anyway. While it would definitely make me feel better if the error went away, so far it hasn't impacted the behavior of my code.